# Unity2d TilemapCollider2D not generating collider for certain sprite images

Tags: unity-game-engine

This specific purple colored image with a bit of opacity isn't getting a collider generated around it by TilemapCollider2D
[image: This specific purple colored image with a bit of opacity isn't getting a collider generated around it by TilemapCollider2D]

[image: What I expected to happen]

[image: What actually happens]

I've tried setting the same settings as the other sprites that don't have this problem but nothing happened. This is also in a brand new project that I've created to test this collider generation only. Everything else is default settings.

Answer (score 0):

TilemapCollider2D relies on a property called ColliderType to determine what shape to draw a collider. Check your collision tile file’s properties, and see if ColliderType is set to None. If so, you can change it to either Sprite or Grid, and it should draw the collider.

For more info:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tile.ColliderType.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason changing the collider type to grid worked, while sprite doesn't work; I wonder if this is something that had to do with the opacity of the sprite itself?

Comment: Glad it worked. In that case, your opacity isn’t a problem. Open the sprite editor and change it from “sprite editor” to “custom physics shape.” Unity uses whatever’s there to generate a collider. My guess is there wasn’t anything specified.